# How to select records starting from a given index in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `Select` as below:

```
(SELECT Id FROM [Samples] Where ForeignKeyId = 4733) -- Returns 2, 5, 7
```

Is it possible to order the return values in such a way that it results like: 5, 7, 2 given a starting value for Id as 5?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So you specify that 5 should be first, how would we know which order the 7 and 2 should be in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well, I would go for something like this.

```
order by case when Id >= 5 then 0 else 1 end, Id
```

so

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

would be ordered as

```
5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: That was an awesome fix!. Thanks a ton!.

Answer (score -1):

you also could try the hint clause and point to the index name so the records will come out in the order of your index is (which most people order asc)

Comment: the OP did state how to order by "Index" regardless if the question seemed different.